# SQLAlchemy many-to-many with single link for multiple tables

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm writing a SQLAlchemy based ORM for a database where multiple pairs of tables are connected by a single link table. This link table has four columns: `from_table_name`, `from_table_key`, `to_table_key`, `to_table_key`.

I want to set up a many to many relationship between two tables in the database. Normally I would do something like:

```
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # some other columns here
    data_from_table_2 = relationship('Table2', secondary='link')


class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # some other columns here
    data_from_table_1 = relationship('Table1', secondary='link')


class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    table_1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table_1.id'), primary_key=True)
    table_2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
```

However, this doesn't work in the given case because I need to specify not just the key in my link table, but also the name of the table being related.

For inspiration, I've been looking through the SQLAlchemy docs on relationships [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-association-tables/) but haven't found anything useful. Does anyone know how to set up a many to many relationship between the two tables above?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the official docs? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

Comment: Why do you have a single relation table for all your relationships? Isn't that worse performance and more complexity? There are already tools to make the normal way (a relation table per many to many relation) easier

Comment: Roel - yes, all of the provided examples create relationships based on primary keys alone and don't rely on the table names.

Comment: nosklo - It's an absolutely terrible design, but unfortunately I didn't come up with it and I can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments to this question, the presented database schema is a confusing design. However, the premise of the question indicates that the schema was created externally and it is up to the developer to come up with an ORM.

The requested relationship can bee implemented manually via class properties and custom queries. For example:

```py
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def data_from_table_2(self):
        with Session() as session:
            return session.query(Reference).filter(
                Link.table_1_id == self.id and 
                Link.table_1_name == self.__tablename__
            ).all()
```

Note that depending on your use case, you may want to use the session attached to the database object

```py
    @property
    def data_from_table_2(self):
        session = object_session(self)
        return session.query(Reference).filter(
            Link.table_1_id == self.id and 
            Link.table_1_name == self.__tablename__
        ).all()
```